# Order between __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__ and alignof(std::max_align_t)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, new-operator, memory-alignment

With GCC and Clang on x86-64/Linux `alignof(std::max_align_t)` and `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` are both equal to `16`.

With MSVC on x86-64/Windows `alignof(std::max_align_t)` is `8` and `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` is `16`.

The standard defines the two terms corresponding to these quantities in [[basic.align]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.align#3):

> An *extended alignment* is represented by an alignment greater than `alignof(std​::​max_­align_­t)`. [...] A type having an extended alignment requirement is an *over-aligned type*. [...] A *new-extended alignment* is represented by an alignment greater than `_­_­STDCPP_­DEFAULT_­NEW_­ALIGNMENT_­_­`.

I don't see that this implies any ordering between the two values, except if I interpret the term "*new-extended*" to imply "*extended*" from the spelling.

Is a conforming implementation of the C++ standard allowed to have

```
alignof(std::max_align_t) > __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__
```

?

And if it does, does this imply that object creation via

```
auto x = ::new(::operator new(sizeof(T))) T;
```

could be undefined behavior for some non-over-aligned type `T`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`std::max_align_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/max_align_t): The alignment of the biggest scalar type
- [`__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#Predefined_macros): The alignment of allocated memory

If I read the standard correct, the new-extended alignment refers to all variants of `void* operator new( std::size_t count, std::align_val_t al);` (Those with `std::align_val_t`).

So assuming the `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` of 8 and `std::max_align_t` of 16, the allocation of long double will have to call `::operator new(16, std::align_val_t(16));`. Something your compiler will have to do for you without you noticing.

In practice, I believe that there are linux implementations out there that guarantee a new alignment of 8. [(moz)jemalloc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1624726/2466431) is one of them, for which this [github-issue](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/issues/1533) seems to confirm that the minimum alignment is 8 instead of 16. (I didn't find official documentation about it)

If you want to use such implementation, you have to update the `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` constant, for more details, see one of my questions:  [Overloading operator new with smaller default alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56713868/2466431).

To answer your last question, I read `auto x = ::new(::operator new(sizeof(T))) T;`  as explicitly calling the operator new instead of simply doing `new T`, in which case, I would assume you indeed have UB if T requires an alignment bigger than the default new alignment. Please note that this also holds if both constants are equal, as you can add `alignas` to the class to change alignment.

Using these kind of classes requires extra care, as using custom allocators when using with `std::vector`.

Comment: `-fnew-alignment` on Clang does indeed allow to produce the ordering, but it does not seem to affect the default `operator new` implementation. The question is whether this is standard-conform behavior or not. If it is conform, then generic library code such as `std::vector` should support it (because `alignof(std::max_align_t)`, not `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`, is the upper bound for alignments that are ["*supported by the implementation in all contexts*"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.align#2).

Comment: If it is standard-conform then I should write library code using placement-new of generic types with that in mind since it should support all types with *fundamental alignment*. Types with explicitly extended alignment with `alignas` are special and I don't need to be generally supported, but basically the question is whether there are types which were not extended this way but for which the result of a call to `operator new(std::size)` is still not sufficiently aligned.

Comment: @walnut The `-fnew-alignment` should be added with a global overload of the ` operator new` Looking at the `std::vector` implementation of libc++, I see explicit call with alignment: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/78d6a7767ed57b50122a161b91f59f19c9bd0d19/include/memory#L1853

Comment: Your second remark is confusing me, however, if you use `std::allocator` or simply `new` instead of calling the operator directly, I don't see problems. If you bypass ` new` and call ::operator new, you'll need to do something special. (Or simply static assert that you don't support this setup yet)

Comment: It surprises me that there is something different here in C++17. In C++14 and before, there is no `align_t` version of `operator new`, but the the other overload is always sufficient for non-over-aligned types. In C++17 however I may need to call the `align_t` version to make sure that it'll work with all non-over-aligned types, going by this answer. The `__libcpp_allocate` function in the libc++ code you linked also switches between the two depending on the `__cplusplus` macro. (The question is rather hypothetical. As you say usually direct calls to `operator new` are not needed.)

Comment: I actually think that before C++14, the allocation of over aligned classes was always UB, which is why [`aligned_alloc`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/align/reference.html#align.reference.functions.aligned_alloc) exists

Comment: Yes, sure. I was referring to non-over-aligned types, those with alignment at most `alignof(std::max_align_t)`, but potentially larger than `_­_­STDCPP_­DEFAULT_­NEW_­ALIGNMENT_­_­`.